# put google map in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, google-maps, ontouchlistener, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to put google map fragment in to AppBar Layout but drag and  zoom control is not possible when map is in Appbar layout.
Is there solution to solve this problem?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                class="com.stategram.app.ui.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```